# Neural Network save weights

Tags: python, neural-network, model

I saved the neural network model as follow

```
model_json = model.to_json()
with open("model.json", "w") as json_file:
json_file.write(model_json)
model.save_weights("model.h5")
```

Then i loaded the model as follow

```
json_file = open('model.json', 'r')
loaded_model_json = json_file.read()
json_file.close()
loaded_model = model_from_json(loaded_model_json)
loaded_model.load_weights("model.h5")
```

After I use that model to the prediction

```
with open('Dialog.txt', 'r', encoding="utf8") as in_file:
text = in_file.read()
sents = nltk.sent_tokenize(text)
count_total = len(x)
count_negative=0
count_neural=0
count_positive=0
for i in range(0,len(sents)):
  text6 =[sents[i]]
  print(text6)
  text6 = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(text6)
  text6 = pad_sequences(text6, maxlen=31, dtype='int32', value=0)
  sentiment = loaded_model.predict(text6,batch_size=1,verbose = 2)[0]
  print(sentiment)
  if(np.argmax(sentiment) == 0):
     count_negative=count_negative+1
     print("negative")
  elif (np.argmax(sentiment) == 2):
     count_positive=count_positive+1
     print("positive")
   elif (np.argmax(sentiment) == 1):
     count_neural=count_neural+1
     print("Neural")
```

[image]

but all probabilities same, how to solve this problem,

Thank you

Comment: first use `print()` to check values in variable - maybe you run code on the same text.

Comment: why do you use two different names `loaded_model` and `model` ? Maybe you loaded model to one variable but you use other variable with wrong weights.

Comment: I print the value but not the same text

Comment: @furas I print the value but not the same text, and used loaded_model, but save issue

Answer (score 0):

This is surprisingly simple to do, I have a couple methods to suggest to do this.

**Method 1:**

Method 1 involves quite literally just copying and pasting the weights in to a file. This might seem quite crude and nonprofessional, but it does the job a lot of the time.

**Method 2:**

Method 2 involves opening a file in python and then dumping the contents of the weights in to the file. This can be done with no additional libraries, you can write and read to the file which is perfect for your application, [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_file_write.asp) is some help if you need it.

**Method 3:**

Method 3 involves using pickle, it is a python library that is widely used. It is very similar to Method 2 but it may have more documentation relating to data science. [Here](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/pickle-python-tutorial) is a resource that might be useful.

I don't necessarily recommend using JSON to store the data, unless you will have multiple layers of weights, which in your case is not necessary.
I hope this helps, good luck and enjoy the rest of your day!